# How to insert a new row with new values (without copying from another object) in HQL..?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using Hibernate.

And i want to persistently store a new row with new values (Without copying from another object) into my database with HQL.

My code in struts action class used to insert a new row is :

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
        Users u = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            u = new Users();
            u.setAge(getAge());
            u.setCity(getCity());
            u.setEmail(getEmail());
            u.setName(getUsername());
            u.setPassword(getPassword());
            u.setSex(getSex());
            session.save(u);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.addActionError("Oops. And Error Encountered...!");
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Code successfully executes without any error. But it is not being persistently stored in my database. I can not see a new row in the database. What can be the error.?

Or if there is any other way to insert a new row with HQL then please tell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that when you are satisfied with an answer you should accept it?

Comment: Hi adranale, i am new to stackoverflow.. So may i know, what is the formal way to accept a answer.

Comment: Can someone solve my aother problem..?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487435/how-to-setup-an-action-link-to-delete-the-row-from-the-table-loaded-from-the-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the session at the end by calling:

```
session.close();
```

better also to do it at the finally block:

```
finally {
  session.close();
}
```